# Swift: INImage does not respect specified width and height

Tags: swift

I am implementing iOS14 widgets with configuration intent that allows users to select a Tweet when the users tap "Edit Widget".

Implementation works well but the image is not sized to the specified width and height in the selection pop up, and seems to be capped at the row height.

Code:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, SelectTweetIntentHandling {
    
    func provideTweetOptionsCollection(for intent: SelectTweetIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<TweetParam>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        let tweetParams = [
            TweetParam(identifier: "1", display: "Title 1", subtitle: "Subtitle 1", image: INImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/69/77/b7/6977b70a129ec184527433bbdf9fe457.jpg")!, width: 200, height: 200)),
            TweetParam(identifier: "2", display: "Title 2", subtitle: "Subtitle 2", image: INImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/69/77/b7/6977b70a129ec184527433bbdf9fe457.jpg")!, width: 200, height: 200)),
            TweetParam(identifier: "3", display: "Title 3", subtitle: "Subtitle 3", image: INImage(url: URL(string: "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/69/77/b7/6977b70a129ec184527433bbdf9fe457.jpg")!, width: 200, height: 200))
        ]
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: tweetParams)
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
    
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        
        return self
    }
    
}
```

Outcome:
[image]

Noticed that I had specified size 200x200 as an exaggeration, but the image size does not respect that. How do I manually size the image to my specified size.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are invoking the shortcut from the Shortcuts app. I noticed the same thing running the shortcut I am working on from the app. However, I do see it respecting the height and width when invoking via voice.

It looks like there is a set height and width for images in this view, and the provided height and width are ignored in this case.

What you can try is using the `imageSize(for:)` method which should respond with "The image size preferred by the response object"

Andy

Comment: How do I use this method? I haven't found any good resource on how to use it...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/inimage/1648800-imagesize
Here is the documentation. You use it on the INImage

Comment: I am having the same issue and @Andy's method is what it should work, but there are ZERO articles about how to use `imageSize(for:)` on INImage. He gave a link saying "here is the documentation", but it has no explanation about usage of the method. He could've easily shared a code snippet, but for some reason chose to share the useless documentation link...

Comment: Did anyone figure this out. The documentation does not say how to use this with INImage